# Consider $P=\forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R [(\exists y\in \mathbb R [ (x_1,y)\in B \land (x_2,y)\in B ]) \implies (x_1=x_2)]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, first-order-logic

Let P be the following statement:

$\forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R [(\exists y\in \mathbb R [ (x_1,y)\in B \land (x_2,y)\in B ]) \implies (x_1=x_2)]$

Let $B= \{(t,t^2) | t\in \mathbb R\}$

Does B satisfy P?

The answer says it does not, but wouldn't $y=0$ work? Then $0^2=0=x$

Comment: I think you **first** define $\;B\;$ and *after that* you write down the statemnet $\;P\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I took this question from my course notes as is

Comment: The order of things may be important. For one, it would be wise to say that $\;B\subset\Bbb R^2\;$ , as for example $\;(x_i,y)\;$ can be an open interval in the real line but also an ordered pair in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ , as obviously intended.

Answer (score 1):

For the statement  $\;P\;$ to be true for the $\;B\;$ you defined , the condition must be fulfilled **always**.

Well, now check that $\;(-1,1)\in B\;,\;\;(1,1)\in B\; $ ...